# Draw a 3D line between two patches in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, line, mesh

I have two sets of coordinates in the form of:

```
v= (x1 y1 z1 a1 b1 c1,
    x2 y2 z2 a2 b2 c2,
    ....,
    xn yn zn an bn cn)
```

These are coordinates of vertices from two meshes. I would like to draw a 3D line joining a vertex in mesh1 to corresponding one in mesh2. I am using the `patch` function to display the two meshes. I tried the `plot3` and it seems to connect lines between points in single mesh only.

Code:

```
% vertex_coordinates contains vertices of matched keypoints obtained using index. Taking first 50 coordinates from the 2 meshes
v=[vertex_coordinates1(1:50,:), vertex_coordinates0(1:50,:)];
x=[v(:,1) v(:,4)];
y=[v(:,2) v(:,5)];
z=[v(:,3) v(:,6)];

figure
p0 = patch('Faces',faces0,'Vertices',vertex0,'FaceColor','blue','FaceAlpha',.5,'edgecolor', 'none');
p1 = patch('Faces',faces1,'Vertices',vertex1,'FaceColor','red','FaceAlpha',.2,'edgecolor', 'none');
axis equal off
hold on
plot3(x',y',z')
```

I am getting something like the image below.[image: lines]
I want something like this.[image: lines 2]

These coordinates are actually the vertices of the matched keypoints in the two meshes. I used indices of the matches to get the coordinates and draw a line between them. Is there something wrong with my code? Or should I be looking into thresholding my matches?

Comment: You certainly do not have the right poitns inside the plot3, but we cant help more because you havent given any [MCVE]

Comment: Sorry but the entire code is bit too big with reading meshes, detecting keypoints and so on. Should I edit my question? I am using [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36316-local-depth-sift-and-scale-invariant-spin-image-local-features-for-3d-meshes) package for this work.

Comment: Genuinely that is the most of the help we can give (you are giving wrong points to plot3). Else you need to create a **Minimal** example that shows this behaviour

Comment: Okay. Can you provide me some general example then, regarding plot3 using vertices in v as seen above? That would be some start for me. :)

Comment: Plot 3 is a basic function, read the docs. I just observed that in your (ridiculously zoomed out) trial all your points are not going where they shoudl. So either your features are wrong, or you are matching them wrong. As a debugging tool, I suggest to replace your `plot3` for a for loop where in each iteration you just draw a line. Draw just 1 or 2 lines in the beggining. that will help you identify the problem

Comment: @AnderBiguri Okay, I will try that. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: We would be happy to try and help with a more general example, but we have no way of even plotting the meshes, let along joining them up. Try writing a few lines to generate a mesh and plot the patches, then we can show you how to join the points up i.e. answer that specific part of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful study I found that I had lot of outliers in my matches. After performing `RANSAC` on the matched keypoints' coordinates I was able to get some okayish outputs.

And the code which helps me draw matches is as follows.

```
v=[best_match_query, best_match_test];
x=[v(:,1), v(:,4)];
y=[v(:,2), v(:,5)];
z=[v(:,3), v(:,6)];
figure
p0 = patch('Faces',faces0,'Vertices',vertex0,'FaceColor','blue','FaceAlpha',.5,'edgecolor', 'none');
p1 = patch('Faces',faces1,'Vertices',vertex1,'FaceColor','red','FaceAlpha',.2,'edgecolor', 'none');
legend('template', 'test')
axis equal off
hold on
plot3(x',y',z')
view(0,90)
```

[image: matches]